# Beam / Cloud Dataflow: How to Add Kafka (or PubSub) topics to Running Stream

Tags: streaming, apache-kafka, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

(How) is it possible to dynamically add or remove topics to a running pipeline as a source or sink (Kafka or PubSub)? Or have as a sink a dynamic pattern like it is possible with BigQuery Table names.

Some background: We have different topics, one per customer, to better facilitate downstream aggregations and also clean/up add them on the fly. Kafka is used to be able to backfill calculations over periods that are longer than possible with PubSub.

The options I have in my mind right now are either extending KafkaIO to support this, or to update the pipeline each time there is a topic added removed (meaning there will be some lags in the stream while its updated). Or maybe I'm having a wrong design pattern in my head and there are other solutions for this.

Comment: I'm facing the same requirement. Is there any news or examples by now that could help me? Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that right now the easiest solution is updating the pipeline.

However, a new API called Splittable DoFn (SDF) is currently in active development; it is already available in the Cloud Dataflow runner in streaming mode and in the Direct runner, and implementation is in progress in Flink and Apex runners.

It makes it possible to do things like "create a PCollection of Kafka topic names and read each of those topics", so you can have one pipeline stage produce names of topics to be read (e.g. the names themselves could arrive over Kafka or Pubsub every time a customer is added, or you could write an SDF to watch the result of a database query returning a list of customers and emit new ones), and another stage reading those topics.

See http://s.apache.org/splittable-do-fn for the design doc of the API, and http://s.apache.org/textio-sdf for an example proposed refactoring of TextIO using this API - you may want to try to modify KafkaIO yourself in a similar fashion.

Comment: Thanks, I checked out the proposal, that should be workable. As I see it there is no way to also make this visible in the UI as a new though without a workflow update, right? (for monitoring purposes to detect individual topics that make make an issue)

Comment: Can you clarify the question? Do you want to add new topics manually using the UI, or do you want the UI to help you find topics, records from which are causing problems downstream? These seem like very different problems.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify: No adding via the UI. It's more about having the ability to separate each topic subscription / writer into a separate step / transform (i.e. box when visualized in the UI). The reason being easier monitoring, error analysis and as I understand also benefitting from some of DataFlows recovery and scaling abilities as these deal with Bundles passed into individual steps. But writing this I actually realize that would mean being able to dynamically updating the graph from the inside, which is only possible via a proper update of the pipeline as of now AFAIK.

Comment: Correct, pipeline update is indeed the proper option for modifying the graph.